# Installed application as root, unable to use by other user

Tags: installation, unity, command-line, launcher

I have installed a program as per the read-me file available with the same, i.e.

```
--How to Install----------------------
* You need login as root *

1. Run "tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2"

2. Run "./install" in TERMINAL to install MobilePartner
   eg: # bash /<path>/install

3. If you had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "The software is exist, do you want overwrites? ([Y]/[N])", enter "y" to overwrites or "n" to exit.

4. If you do not had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "Please input the install path[/usr/local/Mobile_Partner]:". Then you can input install path(fullpath), or you may using the default path(/usr/local/Mobile_Partner) by press ENTER direct

5. Finish installing

--How to run--------------------------
* From shortcut in desktop

* Run MobilePartner in your install path
   eg: # /<install path>/MobilePartner

* Plug in your device, it will run automatically (Not supported in Xandros)
```

So the desktop shortcut is on the home folder (desktop) of root user. Now my question is when I will login as a normal user (not as root), how can I access this application.

Answer (score 3):

Do I assume correctly that you followed the guidelines and installed it while logged in as "root"?

If that is the case then the cleanest solution should be to uninstall the software as root and then reinstall it with "sudo" command.The point is that if you install it while logged in as root, it will install it for the root user. But if you are logged in with your normal user account and run command with "sudo" it will run it with privileges of root but as your normal user.

I have not tried this (!) and it is rather theoretical but hopefully it works for you.

I found this guide about uninstalling MobilePartner:
http://i-zw.blogspot.fi/2013/01/how-to-uninstall-mobile-partner-from.html
But you should log in as root and then run:

```
# /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/UninstallMobilePartner
```

If you succeed in uninstalling it, you should then log root out by typing:

```
# exit
```

Now reinstall the software again but don't do it as root. Instead but "sudo" in front of the command in second step of the original guide. If everything works as I expect, then you should now see the icon on the normal user desktop.

Comment: It's worth adding that there's no reason to ever log in as root in Ubuntu - or presumably any other modern Linux. Sudo will do everything you need. The reason that Ubuntu has no root password by default is exactly this. You don't need to log in as root.